# Can be non-primitive type considered constant in Java?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, constants

Can expression

```
private static final String[] ARRAY = new String[]{"Word1", "Word2"};
```

be considred as constant in Java? Are not constant only primitive types? Is usage of capital letters in this case improper and misleading?

EDIT: Added `private static final` part which I originally forgot. It is apparent that the given array can be changed. The reason for this question was that I saw this (improper) usage in a code and I wanted to confirm my assumptions.

Comment: Ask yourself this question. Can I change the value of `ARRAY`?. If yes, then it is *not* a constant.

Comment: Constant means whos value cannot be changed. So we use final keyword in that case private final static pie=3.14. And variable means its value is variable.

Answer (score 4):

> Can it be considered as constant in Java?

No.

Firstly, if the variable is not `final` you can assign to it.

<sup>(That is what the declaration looked in the version of the question I originally answered.)</sup>

Secondly, even when you declare the variable as `final`, the contents of the array can be trivially changed.  All Java arrays are mutable.

The variable containing the reference is constant.  The object (or the type) is not constant.

> Are not constant only primitive types?

Actually, no.  A `final String` field is also constant.  (And it can even be used in a *constant expression*.)

In fact, any `final` variable containing a reference to an immutable object could be considered to be a constant too.

> Is usage of capital letters in this case improper and misleading?

Yes.  According to the Java Style Guidelines, the upper-case + underscores pattern is only for variables that are attibutes, that are `static` and `final`, and that are either primitives or references to immutable objects.  Your example fails on at least three, if not all four of those requirements.

Answer (score 3):

In particular, this is not a constant, because if you can access the array, you can easily do:

```
ARRAY = new String[]({"Word3"};
```

Capital-case letters don't make a variable a constant. The `final` modifier, however, does:

```
final String[] ARRAY = new String[]{"Word1", "Word2"};
```

As a side note, you can checkout what's the [difference between constant and immutable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019726/constant-object-vs-immutable-object).

Answer (score 1):

Although String is not a primitive data type directly (although Char is), it works some ways as primitive data types. So, if you use final keyword for this type, it will make it constant.

```
final String[] ARRAY = new String[]{"Word1", "Word2"};
```

But for non primitive type, the final keyword doesn't make the the object properties final, it just make the reference to the object final.

Think of type Bird. Say, it has properties like leg.

```
Public class Bird{
int leg=2;
setLegs(int legs){
this.legs=legs};
}
```

Now, if you initialize a Bird, say Parrot with keyword final, by default it will have property like leg=2. Now, the reference is final (Parrot will always refer to type Bird) but you will be still be able to change the properties of this object, like:

```
final Bird Parrot = new Bird();

Parrot.setlegs(3);
```

will change the leg number to 3.

If you want to keep the leg numbers also final, then you need to use it for leg variable also, like:

```
Public class Bird{
final int leg=2;
setLegs(int legs){
this.legs=legs};
}
```

Anyway, I own self don't appreciate playing with bird legs, just for example!

Comment: This is incorrect.  The array reference is constant, the strings are immutable .... but the array can be trivially changed.  It isn't constant ... according to the normal meaning of the word.